# EasyAdmin choiceField bug Symfony

Tags: symfony, crud, roles, easyadmin, choicefield

I think there's a bug in EasyAdmin 3.5.9, but before creating an issue in GitHub, I would like to have people's opinion.

In my User CRUD, I wanted to be able to edit the user role, which wasn't displying by default. So I added it like so in `UserCrudController` class:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    $roles = [
        'User'   => 'ROLE_USER',
        'Agency' => 'ROLE_AGENCY',
        'Admin'  => 'ROLE_ADMIN'
    ];

    return [
        // ...
        ChoiceField::new('roles')
            ->setChoices($roles)->allowMultipleChoices(),
        // ...
    ];
}
```

Here is how it looks in `User` entity:

```
/**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;

    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_AGENCY';
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_ADMIN';

    return array_unique($roles);
}

public function setRoles(array $roles): self
{
    $this->roles = array_values($roles);

    return $this;
}
```

Actually, when I want to edit a user with EasyAdmin by selecting one of these choices, it save the right value in database. But when I come back on the same user to edit it, still all choices are displaying in the field, like I did nothing before. So it seems to be more a displaying issue than a data saving issue.

Here is a quick screen record to understand better:
https://watch.screencastify.com/v/If9xScwQAFqcbbfGBmza

Hope you can help me.

Comment: You are adding all the roles back in whenever you call `UserInterface::getRoles()`. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're absolutely right, I made a dumb mistake. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UserInterface::getRoles()` is manually adding all the roles back in with the set roles. The method should only need the following:

```php
public function getRoles(): array
{
    return array_unique($this->roles);
}
```